# How to get the first character of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need help to see what is wrong with my code; I'm getting the incorrect output.

I need the output to print the first initial and last name (with a period `.` in front of the first initial), for example: `"Anna Lockswell"` should be printed as `"A. Lockswell"`.

So far I have:

```
firstName = input("What is your first name? ") 
lastName = input("What is your last name? ")
str(print(firstname[0:-1], +lastname))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've shown us your code (good!) and told us what it's supposed to do (good!), but you haven't shown us what it's doing instead. Are you getting unexpected output? An error message? If so, what does it say? Please [edit] your question and add that information. (Yes, we can probably figure that out in this case. But including that information is a good habit to get into. See [ask].)

Comment: @Idlehands There are at least 3 other problems with this code

Comment: @DeepSpace you're absolutely right.  I almost feels like this is a pop quiz.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to programming! There are a few issues with what you've posted. First, let's try to get the first letter of `firstname`:

```
firstname = input("What is your first name? ")
# firstname is a string, where each letter acts like an element in an array
# to get the first letter, do this:

first_initial = firstname[0]
```

Per Micha's suggestion, the reason I'm using `firstname[0]` is because I *only* want the first letter. The slice `firstname[0:-1]` will give you everything except the last letter, which isn't quite what you want.

Now, you already have your `lastName`, next to `print`.

You have `str(print("thing to print"))`. The problem here is `print` is a function which doesn't return anything. By wrapping that in `str` you will see the output `None`. To `print`, just call `print`:

```
print(first_initial + '.' + ' ' + lastName)
```

You will need to add a space to the printed output to space out the initial and the last name. There are fancier and more pythonic ways to print, but I feel that this is a sufficient place to start

Comment: It might help to also explain why `firstname[0:-1], +lastname` is nonsensical.

Answer (score 2):

here are a few things that need attention:

1. when you write `firstname[a:b]` it'll return the value of
   `firstname` from char a to char b.
    so when your `firstname` is
   `"anna"` and you'll type `firstname[1:3]` you'll get `'nn'`.
    in this case minus one is equal to the index of the last character which is 3. so `firstname[0:-1]` will return `"ann"`. in your case it should be changed to `firstname[0]`.
2. `str` in the last line is completely unnecessary. `str` is used for converting other types to string. for example `str(1)` returns `'1'`.
3. `print(a,b)` will print `2 3` assuming `a = 2` and `b = 3` so you'll need to use `print( a + '.' + b)` for getting `2.3`. ( there are many other ways to do this).

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these:

```
>>> print('{}. {}'.format(firstname[0], lastname))
A. Lockswell

>>> print(firstname[0] + '. ' + lastname)
A. Lockswell

>>> print(f'{firstname[0]}. {lastname}')
A. Lockswell
```

Comment: I did not down vote your answer but I think, given how confused OP is, your answer would benefit if you explain in great detail what and why OP did wrong (and not so much, give the correct answer for free). But this is just my opinion and can be completely wrong of course.